# Why is alternative sign in Hessian subdeterminant a necessary and sufficient condition for multivariable maxmization

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, optimization

The necessary and sufficient condition for a maximal point in a multivariable function is the following

$$\text{i. } x \text{ must satisfy first order condition}$$

$$\text{ii. } |H|_1 < 0 \text{ and subdeterminants have alternative signs}$$

Is the second condition equivalent to having all diagonal elements less than zero? If not why is the further restriction on non diagonal elements necessary?

Answer (score 0):

No it isn't, it could have all diagonals at $0$ for example. We need all eigenvalues of the Hessian to be negative. This can be proved by taking $g(x) = -f(x)$ and applying the same procedure you have likely covered for proving local minima using Taylor expansion.

I can add some proof if need be.